# partial derivative within integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-differential-equations

Can anybody give a solution for G, where $G(x,y)=\int_0^1\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x,sy)ds $.

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x,sy)$ looks a bit strange to me, seeing as $y$ isn't really one of the two free variables in $g$. Maybe I'm just being overly pedantic, though. If you say $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x,y,s)$ where $f(x,y,s)=g(x,sy)$, then that's more to my aesthetic liking, but probably way too verbose.

Comment: Hint: Treat $x$ as fixed. Apply FTC.